# iPhone app - load an UIImage and the put a small positional icon (image) on it?

Tags: iphone, icons, uiimageview, uiimage, overlay

I have looked everywhere for what should be a simple concept.  I can load an image(s) with UIView/UIImageView and just want to place a smaller icon/image on top of the original image at a given position.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You should do like Ole Begermann says, and use the frame of the large UIImageView to make sure that your small image is inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Create another `UIImageView` with the second image and position it on top of the first one.

Comment: Thanks - I did that but I may need to adjust the frame of the second UIImageView.